# How to show this function is continuous?

Tags: real-analysis

I was trying to show that for points $x,y \in S^n$ there is a continuous function $f: [0,1] \to S^n$ with $f(0) = x, f(1) = y$. My idea is $$ f(t) = {(1-t)x + ty \over \|(1-t)x + ty \|}$$

but then I was confused because not sure how to show it is continuous? Is it continuous? Can someone help me show it is continuous if it is?

Comment: Show that it is build up from elementary functions, which are continous, by composition, addition...

Comment: There is a problem if $x$ and $y$ are diametrically opposite.

Comment: Well, does there exist a continuous function $[0,1]\to S^n$ which is onto?

Comment: Ignore my last comment, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ and $y$ are not diametrically opposite, then your function $f$ is fine.
It is continuous because $t \, \longmapsto \, (1-t)x + ty$ and $x \, \longmapsto \, \Vert x \Vert$ are continuous and $\Vert tx+(1-t)y \Vert \neq 0$ for all $t \in [0,1]$. Then $f$ is continuous.

If $x$ and $y$ are diametrically opposite, take another point $z$ on the sphere, different from $x$ or $y$. The previous part of the answer gives you a continuous path on the sphere from $x$ to $z$ and another one from $z$ to $y$. "Concatenate" these two paths and you will get a continuous path $g$ on the sphere which satisfies : $g(0)=x$ and $g(1) =y$.

Comment: Thank you. But why it does not work if the points are diametrically opposite? If $y=-x$ then 
$$f(t) = {(1-t)x - tx \over \|(1-t)x - tx \|}$$
and $f(0) = x$ and $f(1)=-x$, no?

Comment: No, if $x$ and $y$ are diametrically opposite, $\Vert (1-t)x - tx \Vert = 0$ if $t=\frac{1}{2}$. So $f$ does not define a continuous map on the sphere from $x$ to $y$.